# SimpleXML Addchild in existing parent element in XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I want to add another "Rasse" element into my existing xml file but this is basicly what I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="katzen.xsd">

</catalog>
<Rasse previewimage="http://http://www.planet-wissen.de/natur/haustiere/katzen/dasmiauenisteherseltenzuhoeren100~_v-gseapremiumxl.jpg">
  <titel>sdfsdf</titel>
  <aussehen fell="langhaar">sdfsdf</aussehen>
  <charakter>
    <Wohnungskatze wohnung="ja"/>
    <Familienkatze kinder="ja"/>
    <Bewegungsbedarf bewegung="hoch"/>
    <Garteneignung garten="ja"/>
  </charakter>
</Rasse>
```

What happens here, is that "Rasse" is not included in "catalog"

This is my php Code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('katzi.xml');

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());

$previewimagee = $_POST['previewimage'];
$titell = $_POST['titel'];
$aussehenn = $_POST['aussehen'];
$felll = $_POST['fell'];
$Wohnungskatzee = $_POST['Wohnungskatze'];
$wohnungg = $_POST['wohnung'];
$Familienkatzee = $_POST['Familienkatze'];
$kinderr = $_POST['kinder'];
$Bewegungsbedarff = $_POST['Bewegungsbedarf'];
$bewegungg = $_POST['bewegung'];
$Garteneignungg = $_POST['Garteneignung'];
$gartenn = $_POST['garten'];


$root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('Rasse'));
$Rasse = simplexml_import_dom ($root);
$Rasse->addAttribute('previewimage', $previewimagee);
$Rasse->addChild('titel', $titell);
$aussehen = $Rasse->addChild('aussehen', $aussehenn);
$aussehen->addAttribute('fell', $felll);
$charakter = $Rasse->addChild('charakter');
$Wohnungskatze = $charakter->addChild('Wohnungskatze', $Wohnungskatzee);
$Wohnungskatze->addAttribute('wohnung', $wohnungg);
$Familienkatze = $charakter->addChild('Familienkatze', $Familienkatzee);
$Familienkatze->addAttribute('kinder', $kinderr);
$Bewegungsbedarf = $charakter->addChild('Bewegungsbedarf', $Bewegungsbedarff);
$Bewegungsbedarf->addAttribute('bewegung', $bewegungg);
$Garteneignung = $charakter->addChild('Garteneignung', $Garteneignungg);
$Garteneignung->addAttribute('garten', $gartenn);

$dom->save("katzi.xml");
```

Does someone has an idea how to include "Rasse" in "catalog" so that I can add how many new "Rasse" entrys I want?

Comment: You want to add multiple "Rasse" elements into the "catalog" element of your xml, yet there is no mention of "catalog" in the code you posted.
The result-xml does not seem to be generated by the code you posted.

Comment: So where and how would you mention "catalog" in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Consider starting from root element with `$dom->documentElement` to capture the `<catalog>` element, then build out tree from there without `simplexml_import_dom` route but using `createElement`, `addChild`, and `setAttribute` methods:

```
$root = $dom->documentElement;
$Rasse = $root->appendChild($dom->createElement('Rasse'));

$Rasse->setAttribute('previewimage', $previewimagee);
$Rasse->appendChild($dom->createElement('titel', $titell));
$aussehen = $Rasse->appendChild($dom->createElement('aussehen', $aussehenn));
$aussehen->setAttribute('fell', $felll);
$charakter = $Rasse->appendChild($dom->createElement('charakter'));
$Wohnungskatze = $charakter->appendChild($dom->createElement('Wohnungskatze', $Wohnungskatzee));
$Wohnungskatze->setAttribute('wohnung', $wohnungg);
$Familienkatze = $charakter->appendChild($dom->createElement('Familienkatze', $Familienkatzee));
$Familienkatze->setAttribute('kinder', $kinderr);
$Bewegungsbedarf = $charakter->appendChild($dom->createElement('Bewegungsbedarf', $Bewegungsbedarff));
$Bewegungsbedarf->setAttribute('bewegung', $bewegungg);
$Garteneignung = $charakter->appendChild($dom->createElement('Garteneignung', $Garteneignungg));
$Garteneignung->setAttribute('garten', $gartenn);

$dom->save("katzi.xml");
```